# How make a QR Code in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I need to create a QR code reader using Android Studio. 
How can I do that?
I created an app but it needs an other application that scan qr code.
I'd want create a simple QR code reader since the begin.

Comment: Better to search on _Google_.

Comment: I did. But there's no much information.

Comment: [Check this?](https://www.google.co.in/search?newwindow=1&q=qr+code+reader+in+android+example&revid=1905494621&sa=X&ved=0CGQQ1QIoAWoVChMIgtSo8_PpxwIVgwSOCh0spwqP&biw=1366&bih=667)

Comment: "I searched a lot, but didn't find anything". Really? Then you need to improve your googling skills.

Answer (score 0):

Barcode detection (including QR code) is integrated in the latest Google Play Services.
You can follow this codelab by google to get to know it:
https://search-codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/bar-codes#1

Here was the announcement:
http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2015/08/barcode-detection-in-google-play.html

Comment: Thanks Ivo. So If I follow that link I'll create an app that reade QR Code?